# Three.js: Make raycaster's direction the same as object's

Tags: three.js

all!
I'm currently making a game in THREE.js and while I've got the 'vertical' collision with the ground sorted with a raycaster, I am having trouble with horizontal collision. I've consulted a few tutorials, but they don't do what I want them to.

Basically, I've got a load of cubes. I've given them a random y-axis rotation and used translate to make them move 'forward' - pretty basic stuff. How do I get a raycaster to point the same direction as the cube, almost like a line sticking out of its 'nose'? i.e. how do I get a raycaster's direction to copy that of an object?

It's been a while since I've been on here, but kind regards anyway,
Matthew

Comment: Try `object.getWorldDirection( vector )`.

Comment: You star. Thanks for the quick reply! I'm gonna give it a go!